# Why is my output blank when trying to read two standard in reverse order?

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to get a better understanding of variables and types. I have been given a problem to "Read two integers from the standard input, then output them in reverse." I have my code completed, but it is not printing in reverse order. Any ideas?

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //put your code here

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scanner.nextInt(3);
    int b = scanner.nextInt(2);
    System.out.print(a - b);
  }
}
```

Comment: The argument you pass is the radix. Are you sure you pass the right one? Unless you're using binary, you're not gonna trigger it. IIRC scanner by radix takes the first one that match, but it blocks until it's received. Also, 3 isn't a valid radix

Comment: Don't use unrelated tags for your questions.

Comment: @forpas when going through the Kotlin tutorials it says if you have questions in regards of this to use the Kotlin tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.print(a - b);` will print the result of `a - b` subtraction. You need to create a String to display the values. You most likely don't want to use `Scanner.nextInt(radix)`, that's not part of your problem statement. Instead just use `Scanner.nextInt()` which will use default radix of 10.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = scanner.nextInt();
int b = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("" + b + " - " + a);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem was to print b and then a, or to print a and b with their digits reversed. But yours is just as good an answer to an ambiguous question.

Comment: When you say "Create a string to display the values" does that mean I need to create a     int and attach it to a set of numbers? Or a string and attach to text?

Comment: When you print something to `System.out` it gets displayed in console as text. If you want to display `3-2` you need to make it a String e.g. `"3-2"` or `String.format("%d-%d", 3, 2)`. Check out [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could write it using interpolated strings like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val a = scanner.nextInt()
    val b = scanner.nextInt()
    println("$b - $a")
}
```